# SQLite Error on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hi i am new windows phone 8

i am using windows 8 OS and Visualstudio 2012,

i had followed the steps in

```
https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8
```

but when i am adding,

```
SQLite for Windows Phone as a reference i am getting an error,


  The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" 
  is not supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.WP80, Version=3.8.4.3". 
  Please consider changing the \targeted processor architecture of 
  your project (in visual studio this can be done   
  through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
  supported by the SDK: "x86,ARM"
```

In my Configuration Manager it sets Any CPU what can i do please give me any solution.

Comment: Go to "Add New Platform Configuration" and look for the "ARM" option in one of the drop-downs.

Comment: Yes now that error goes away but,New Error : The type or namespace name 'Community' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please any one tell me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this,it may help you

**Step:1**

Go to "Add New Platform Configuration" and look for the "ARM" option in one of the drop-downs

**Step:2**

```
Project -> Properties

Click on the Build tab.

In the "Configuration" dropdown, select "All configurations".

In the "Platform" dropdown, select "All platforms".

Append ";USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE" to the "Conditional compilation symbols" textbox.
```